# ROS Industrial website is often down

Tags: ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are working on a project to explore the possibilities of ROS Industrial for SME companies. However, the ROS Industrial website (rosindustrial.org) is very often not reachable and this is not beneficial for the confidence of companies in the technology. Is it possible to host the ROS Industrial website at a more reliable provider?

I have not experienced problems with the ros.org website.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262912/ros-industrial-website-is-often-down/) by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2017-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for the information. Indeed, this is an issue within our organisation. The IP address of rosindustrial.org is blocked by our firewall because the website andyschwinn.com (which doesn't exist anymore) had the same IP address as rosindustrial.org and is reported as a source of cryptolocker malware. Our system administrator has manually removed the block. However, I expect that more organisations will have the same issue.

---

Originally posted by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) with karma: 159 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-01**:
Could I please ask you to not post answers, unless you are answering your own question? ROS Answers is not a regular forum, but a Q&A site. Discussion is best done in comments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosindustrial.org site is hosted on square space which has very little downtime:

http://www.webhostingstuff.com/uptime/SquareSpace.html

This may be a regional issue. We are currently looking into this, so if you could post some more data, that would be helpful.

Thank you,
-Austin

---

Originally posted by [aderic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28730/aderic/) with karma: 31 on 2017-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3